# Play! framework fetch full page contents

Tags: java, playframework, web-scraping

I need to fetch the full contents of an URL withouth using the play! 1 WS library because of a SSL issue with that lib and the site I need to scrap.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
new URL("someurl").getContent();
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getContent()